# How to determine nr value using mechanize in python

Tags: python, mechanize

I am writing script to login website. see below script

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()

print "Login to myweb"

browser.open('https://www.example.com/index.php/devicelogin')

#Login page. Give user credentials 
browser.select_form(nr=0)
browser.form["username"] = 'username'
browser.form["passwd"] = 'password'
browser.submit()

html = browser.response().read()

print html
```

When i run it the it give me error.

```
Login to myweb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
  browser.form["username"] = 'username'
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 2780, in __setitem__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3101, in find_control
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_form.py", line 3185, in _find_control
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'username'
```

Now if i change `nr=1` in `browser.select_form(nr=0)` then it works fine.

So how can i determine `nr` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From mechanize [source code](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L462):

> nr, if supplied, is the sequence number of the form (where 0 is the
>           first).

So the first form in the page is 0, the second is 1, the third is 2, etc.

However, if you cannot determine the number of the form by counting them and the form doesn't have a name, you could do:

```
for n in range(len(browser.forms())):
   browser.select_form(nr=n)
   try:
       browser.form["username"] = 'username'
       browser.form["passwd"] = 'password'
       browser.submit()
   except mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError:
       continue  # check next form
   break 

html = browser.response().read()
```

In case of a named form, you could skip all the counting and retrieve it by simply calling `browser.select_form('my_form_name')`

Finally, if your form doesn't have a name attribute and you don't want to loop through the forms, you might want to have a look at [Mechanicalsoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup), which provides you with the possibility to navigate through the document as you would do with BeautifulSoup (since it is built on it) and with a Mechanize-like API.

Comment: Is it possible to get `nr` value of form which i opened here directly without loop?

Comment: It is a bit hard to say without seeing the html code. I guess it depends whether you could identify the form in some way other than its number/index (e.g. name, id, etc.) @Jayesh